# Kamon broadcast Context is not reading HTTP headers

Tags: scala, kamon

I want to configure kamon to inspect each request and store a header value in the context in order to get access to this context from anywhere in the app. I took an example from kamon docs:  https://kamon.io/docs/latest/core/context/

My webapp is built with lagom and some custom play routes. This is the config for kamon context in the application.conf

```
kamon.context.codecs {
  string-keys {
    request-id = "X-Request-ID"
  }
}
```

and this is an example of my route

```
    case GET(p"/helloWorld") =>
      action(parser.default) { request =>

        val xrequestKeyID = Context.key[String]("X-Request-ID", null)
        val requestID1: String = Kamon.currentContext().get(xrequestKeyID)
        println(s"requestID1=$requestID1")


        val headers = request.headers.toString()
        println(s"Header=${headers}")

        Results.Accepted
      }
```

when making a curl with a header, Kamon is not reading the http header.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:11000/helloWorld' --header 'X-Request-ID: hello'
```

Here is the result in the terminal.

```
requestID1=
Header=List((Timeout-Access,<function1>), (Remote-Address,127.0.0.1:56854), (Raw-Request-URI,/helloWorld), (Tls-Session-Info,[Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]), (Host,localhost:11000), (User-Agent,curl/7.58.0), (Accept,*/*), (X-Request-ID,hello))
```

Do you know how to use kamon context for broadcast keys?

Thank you very much!